# Return relationship has one of belongs to many

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have exams that belongs to many questions.

Some question have a parent question.

Now I need a function inside of exams that returns me all parent questions.^

I got this piece of code

```
public function getQuestionParentsAttribute() {
    $array = [];
    foreach($this->questions->load('parent') as $q) {
        if($q->parent !== null)
        $array[] = $q->parent;
    }
    return $array;
}


class Exam extends Model {
    public function questions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class);
    }
}

class Question extends Model {
    public function parent() {
        return $this->hasOne(Question::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

but I want to have it as relationship, not as attribute, so i can call it like
`$exam->with('parentQuestion')->get()`;

Comment: Could you paste relation definition between exams and questions and between questions and their parents?

Comment: added the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way so it is not appended for every use:

```
class Exam extends Model {
    public function setParents() {
        $array = $this->questions()->where('parent_id', '>', 0)->with('parent')->get();
        $this->parents =  array_pluck($array, 'parent');
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
$exam = Exam::find($id);
$exam->setParents();
return $exam;
```

I am sure it's not the best, but the best right now.